# Doing a Roth IRA transfer this year for last year

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

I did a simple backdoor Roth IRA for the year 2021 just now i.e. in Feb. 2022. Thus I have not gotten any 1099-R forms for 2021. So do I file this in my 2022 tax return next year? Or can I still file it this year in 2021 tax return?

Comment: You still must report your non-deductible Traditional IRA contribution, that you designated as for 2021, by filing form 8606 part 1 on your 2021 tax return. That will leave a basis. Since the conversion counts as a 2022 conversion, you will report it by filing form 8606 part 2 on your 2022 tax return. It will use up the basis left from 2021, and you should pay no taxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollovers (including conversions) are not backdated. You did the conversion in Feb 2022 - it will be reported on your 2022 tax return.

Comment: Thank you! This is a hard question to phrase w.r.t. searching online, so couldn't find anything. Makes sense since this should reflect tax documents that I will get next year.